# How can I convert a unicode hex value to a string character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, hex

I have data that I have scraped from html which has in it unicode hex references. For example a string may contain

```
"Store below 25&#xB0;C." or "She&#x27;s not the one"
```

How can I convert this Unicode hex reference to a string? I want to use Node to return strings like: "Store below 25°C." or "She's not the one".

Thanks in advance